# How to write this line in C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm using Visual C++ to call a web service. I need to bypass the invalid SSL certificates since I'm getting this error -

> The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

While writing the same thing in C#, I used this line -

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

and it worked for me.

How do I achieve the same thing in Visual C++? How do I write the same line in Visual C++?

Comment: "Real" C++ or C++CLI?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg : C++ CLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create callback object explicitly and assign it to corresponding property.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::Net::Security;
using namespace System::Security::Cryptography::X509Certificates;


static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
        Object^ sender,
        X509Certificate^ certificate,
        X509Chain^ chain,
        SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // create callback object, pointing to your function
    System::Net::Security::RemoteCertificateValidationCallback^ clb = gcnew RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
    // assign it to the property
    System::Net::ServicePointManager::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = clb;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me what exactly are we doing here?

Answer (score 0):

C++/CLI in VS 2010 doesn't support lambdas, so you'll have to write your delegate as a normal function:

```
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::Net::Security;
using namespace System::Security::Cryptography::X509Certificates;

bool returnTrueCallback(
    Object^ sender, X509Certificate^ certificate, X509Chain^ chain,
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}

...

ServicePointManager::ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    gcnew RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(returnTrueCallback);
```

Comment: I get these errors!
Error 1 error C2065: 'returnTrueCallback' : undeclared identifier
Error 2 error C3350: 'System::Net::Security::RemoteCertificateValidationCallback' : a delegate constructor expects 2 argument(s)

Comment: callback has to be static as in my answer. Otherwise you have to provide pointer to actual object instance.

Comment: This works for me. Free functions are already static, they don't need that keyword.